# Intellij Plugin - Run Command and show the process below

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

We all know that IDEA has a maven intellij plugin. When we double click the button like "clean", the procedure of "clean" will be shown below:
[The clean procedure is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIHnp.png)

And in my plugin development, I also created a button and its action is to be double clicked and execute some command.

In the Action of the button I've tried using:

```java
    Process process = null;
    try {
        String cmd = "mvn clean";
        process = runtime.exec(cmd);
        System.out.println(cmd);
        process.waitFor();
        process.destroy();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
```

But after I executed it, "mvn clean" was exactly executed, while the procedure didn't be shown below.

So my question is: Is there any java.swing component or method can I achieve the effect above in the image I provide?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: You should consult the SDK documentation about how to run external process and show it's results in IDE, see [Run Configurations](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/run_configurations.html). Check also the [plugin development forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development).